# server listed in backscatterer twice in 2 months

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot

My server was listed twice in a 2 months time window in backscatterer.org blacklist, for a low severity.
I'm not finding anything about the reason of blacklisting.
Would there be anyone to help me to find the reason ?

I am on a Debian Jessie server using postfix with dovecot, protected with fail2ban on authentification attempts.
I may have forgotten something on the configuration, but there were no problem in the past time, server was nearly never listed.

Comment: Have you tried using the tools over here? https://mxtoolbox.com/

Answer (score 1):

The **why** is simple; as quoted from their homepage;

> Listing Policy is quite simple: Every IP which backscatters (**Sending
>   misdirected bounces or misdirected autoresponders or sender
>   callouts**) will be listed the next 4 weeks here. Currently 88109 IP's
>   are known for abusing the NET in this way!

The **who** is more complex to find; I would suggest checking the outgooing queue for any user that abuse; Please see that question for that topic; [How to log full outgoing mails in Postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/183283/how-to-log-full-outgoing-mails-in-postfix)